# Breakdown 「欲しけりゃくれてやるぜ」meaning

Tags: meaning, conjugations, manga

> おれの財宝か？欲しけりゃくれてやるぜ。。。(One Piece)

Especially the part "欲しけりゃ" (from what I gather, it's an inflection of 欲しい?) Is this a common construct? How can I break it down?

How can I better search for this kind of thing?

- someone on hinative translated the second sentence as "if you want I'll give it to you";
- Google translator seems to ignore 欲しけりゃ completely if I don't put a comma in the middle.

Comment: れば → りゃ. 　Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of りゃ in this phrase?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%82%8a%e3%82%83-in-this-phrase)

Comment: (JFYI, くれてやる means: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6405/9831)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the links that have been provided to you in the comments below your question do not satisfy your curiosity:

.....

欲しけりゃ　means the same thing as　欲しければ

～けりゃ is an informal variation on ～ければ. Examples can be found [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%91%E3%82%8A%E3%82%83).

The phrase in question would be standardized as:

> 「欲しければあげるよ。。。」’I’ll give it to you if you want it.’

The translation for くれてやる reads thus:

> 自分より目下の者や、いまいましく思っている者に物を与える  - Said when giving something to someone who is either below you in status or who you do not think kindly of.

In this case, it can be read as ‘I will grant you my treasure.’

This question was asked on Yahoo 知恵袋. You can find it [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1127606591).

> My treasure?
>
> If you want it I’ll give it to you.
>
> Search for it!
>
> I’ve amassed there the entire world.

Comment: `someone who seems upset` -- In「いまいましく思っている者」, the subject of いまいましく思う is 自分, and the object is 者. 「自分がその者をいまいましく思っている」"I am disgusted with that person" ->「(自分が)いまいましく思っている者」"Someone whom I am disgusted with" (like... "Someone I hate")

Comment: Oh, so basically りゃ is a contraction of the conditional form. These contractions always get me! Thanks for all the information, the examples were all very helpful!

Comment: @dvlcube:  Thanks for the feedback. Not to be picky (while actually being picky), It’s not really a contraction, just a phonetic change  to a  more casual spoken form (音変化）. 
Often, は and ば are changed to や. たべれば→たべりゃ, それは→そりゃ・そりゃあ, etc.
This is also seen in other common examples, such as なんだ→なんじゃ, では→じゃ, etc.  Even どちら, どち, and どっち are examples of this (taken from now unused readings of 何方) .

Comment: あの・・・くどいようですが、「忌々しく思っている者」を "Someone who seems upset" と訳すのは間違ってますけど・・・・・もうそのままでよろしい？

Comment: 「いまいましい」って、persistent って意味あんの？　ふええ

Comment: @Chocolate: 「いまいましく思っている者に」の訳に引っかかっていて、ちゃんと意味を理解していなかったのは明らかですね... 三度目のattemptは大丈夫ですか？すみません、わさわさ。

Comment: 良いと思います。「～を忌々しく思う」は「～を嫌う、憎む、憎いと思う」に似ていると思います。うまく英語に訳せなくてすみません・・・